# How to correctly read encoded get varible

Tags: javascript, php

I have a search engine that does the following things:

Read an input value and encode it using js, then redirect.

```
//read and save into `query` var
window.location.href = "/search/" + encodeURIComponent(query);
```

So if user enters

> What is the meaning of & sign ?

The ulrl can't end up like this;

```
expample.com/search/What%20is%the%meaning%20of%20&this%20sign?
```

And instead get:

```
expample.com/search/What%20is%the%meaning%20of%20&26this%20sign%3F
```

Now when I dump the $_GET['parameters'] i get

```
string() "search/What is the meaning of "
```

I expect to get:

```
What is the meaning of & sign ?
```

I have tried:

```
$val = urldecode($_GET['parameters']);
```

But I have had no luck, Maybe I should change the way javascript encodes the url, what are your suggestions?

Comment: Where is the `&this` coming from in your original encoded string?  That is the problem.  That `&` should be encoded.

Comment: what is `console.log(query);` ?

Comment: The original has the &, and the emcoded has %3F instead, bit when I Reader the GET value is as is %3F would not be there, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

PHP decodes URL paramaters automatically into the [`$_GET` superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) as long as you're using the standard [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) syntax. If you use your own syntax, you have to roll your own code (you already have custom code in the input form).

The raw URL can be fetched from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and parsed with the text manipulation tool of your choice. It's worth noting that this isn't an uncommon set up (many PHP frameworks do things this way).

Comment: Oh thanks, I think this will lead me to the solution, I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned that you're calling the following to obtain the value of the user's query:

```
$val = urldecode($_GET['parameters']);
```

This implies that a URL calling your PHP page would have a shape similar to the following:

```
http://foo.bar/?parameters=<the query here>
```

The important thing to include in the URL is `?`; when a URL is parsed, the `?` signals that whatever comes afterward is a URL-encoded query.

Thus, in your javascript:

```
window.location.href = "/search/?parameters=" + encodeURIComponent(query);
```

Then your existing code should work.

Comment: I just tried it and my url looks cool but... Sorry I pressed enter before, ill edit this comment in a sec

Comment: Also, I would assume that PHP would automatically URL-decode the string, so I don't think you would have to call `urldecode`.

Comment: I can not longer edit my latest comment so here it is:   I just tried it and my url looks cool but when I enter the ampersand in the query, even though it is encoded when I dump it the query is crop until the moment the ampersand was entered. It should not happen since there are not ampersand signs in the url, Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you will want to take a look at the [URI specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986). If you have multiple query parameters, the *values* should be URI encoded. Not the keys, and not the entire string. Just the values.

Comment: I'll take a look Tobe

Answer (score -1):

Just do

on client-side

> window.location.href = "/search/" + query;

and on server-side

> $val = urldecode($_GET['parameters']);

Comment: The problem is that if the query has an ampersand or a question mark is read as a url part, e.g: The ampersand works as parameters separator so the $_GET variable is not completely read, to be sure I tried and I confirmed what I just said, thanks anyway.

Comment: No. Your client side code will fail to encode the query, so any special characters won't be escaped. Your server side code attempts to double-decode it, so it will break for different reasons.